# How do you validate XML stored procedure parameter against XSD with namespace in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, xml, stored-procedures, xsd

I have a dataset of `People` and I want to be able insert that set into my table but validate that the input XML matches an `XML SCHEMA COLLECTION` I have created.  In a simpler version of my code that does not use namespaces, I am able to accomplish this but I want to be able to do it with user defined data types as well as namespaces.  When I try with the code below, I get **Msg 2260, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_InsertPerson, Line 16
XQuery [nodes()]: There is no element named 'People'**

I have tried a number of things and haven't been able to figure out how to accomplish this.  Here is the code to create the stored procedure:

```
USE [A_IndexingTest]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertPerson]
(
    @xmlData XML (dbo.PersonSchemaCollection)
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.Person
  (LastName, FirstName, Gender, DateOfBirth, IsFriendly)
SELECT 
  person.field.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  person.field.value('(LastName)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  person.field.value('(Gender)[1]', 'char(1)'),
  person.field.value('(DateOfBirth)[1]', 'datetime'),
  person.field.value('(IsFriendly)[1]', 'bit')
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/People/Person') AS person(field)

SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)
END
GO
```

And to create the XSD:

```
USE [A_IndexingTest]
GO
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION [dbo].[PersonSchemaCollection] AS
N'
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     targetNamespace="http://example.org/People"
     xmlns:tns="http://example.org/People">

    <xs:simpleType name="firstName">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
        <xs:maxLength value="100" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="lastName">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
        <xs:maxLength value="100" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="gender">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
        <xs:maxLength value="1" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="dateOfBirth">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="isFriendly">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:boolean">          
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="People">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Person">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="FirstName" type="tns:firstName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="LastName" type="tns:lastName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="Gender" type="tns:gender" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="DateOfBirth" type="tns:dateOfBirth" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="IsFriendly" type="tns:isFriendly" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>'
```

Comment: Side note: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Comment: Thank you for your comment and I hadn't thought of that before. This is a standard at the company that I work for and I will mention it to the higher ups but it's out of my hands for now :(

Comment: My usual recommendation would be for no prefixes on any type of SQL object - the syntax is such that you can tell what type of object you're looking at just by where it appears (except for views and tables, which should, rightly, not be treated any differently from each other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I'm using a `targetNamespace` it appears I need to reference the namespace when the stored procedure gets created.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertPerson] (
    @xmlData XML (dbo.PersonSchemaCollection)
)
AS
BEGIN

-- this is the part that I was missing
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://example.org/People' as tns)

INSERT INTO dbo.Person
  (LastName, FirstName, Gender, DateOfBirth, IsFriendly)
SELECT 

  -- additionally note the tns prefix for all of the fields and nodes
  person.field.value('(tns:FirstName)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  person.field.value('(tns:LastName)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  person.field.value('(tns:Gender)[1]', 'char(1)'),
  person.field.value('(tns:DateOfBirth)[1]', 'datetime'),
  person.field.value('(tns:IsFriendly)[1]', 'bit')
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/tns:People/tns:Person') AS person(field)

SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)
END
GO
```